# How to remove Item by name member from a vector of Items?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, find

I want to remove an `Item` by searching the name of the item using `find` and iterator but is not working? I tried many different ways and my console is just showing a lot of errors.

Here is my code:

```
struct Item {
  struct Item {
  string name;
  float price;
  unsigned int quantity;
};

Item i1 = {"Item 2", 0.05, 3};
Item i2 = {"Item 1", 0.10, 1};
Item i3 = {"Item 3", 0.25, 2};
  
vector <Item> inventory;
```

```
// Remove an Item, by name, from the inventory
// Return true if the Item is present and has been removed, false otherwise
bool Inventory::removeItem(string name) {
  if(hasItem(name)) {
      inventory.erase(remove(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), name), inventory.end());
      return true;
  } else {  
     return false;
  }
}

//This function checks if hasItem
bool Inventory::hasItem(string name) {
  for (Item i : inventory) {
        if (i.name == name) {
            return true; 
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't know if I'm not getting the correct value, or I need to find the index of the value (name).

Here are the errors:

```
In file included from inventory.cpp:1:
In file included from ./inventory.h:7:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/algorithm:61:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/predefined_ops.h:241:17: error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('Item' and 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >')
        { return *__it == _M_value; }
                 ~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:869:7: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization '__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>
      > >::operator()<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Item *, std::vector<Item, std::allocator<Item> > > >' requested here
        if (!__pred(__first))
             ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:906:19: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__remove_if<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Item *, std::vector<Item, std::allocator<Item> > >,
      __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >' requested
      here
      return std::__remove_if(__first, __last,
                  ^
inventory.cpp:56:23: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::remove<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Item *,
      std::vector<Item, std::allocator<Item> > >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >'
      requested here
      inventory.erase(remove(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), name), inventory.end());
                      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/system_error:292:3: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion
      from 'Item' to 'const std::error_code' for 1st argument
  operator==(const error_code& __lhs, const error_code& __rhs) noexcept
  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/system_error:297:3: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion
      from 'Item' to 'const std::error_code' for 1st argument
  operator==(const error_code& __lhs, const error_condition& __rhs) noexcept
```

Comment: please include a [mcve] and the compiler errors in the quesiton

Comment: What does the debugger tell you? p.s. `hasItem` can use `std::any_of`. and you can pass the string by const ref, to prevent a copy

Comment: I just update the question with some of the debugger errors.

Comment: please include a complete example. What is `inventory` ? what is `Item` ?

Comment: The code is updated including struct and vector

Answer (score 2):

You need [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) with a function that will match names only:

```
  auto newEnd = std::remove_if(inventory.begin(), 
                               inventory.end(), 
                               [&name](const auto& item){return item.name == name;});
  inventory.erase(newEnd, inventory.end());
```

I moved `remove_if` to separate line to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line

```
inventory.erase(remove(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), name), inventory.end());
```

`inventory` seems to be a container of `Item`. But you cannot compare an object of `Item` to a `std::string` (`name`).
If there's just one item you need to remove, you can solve this using `find_if` with a lambda

```
bool Inventory::removeItem(string const& name) {
   if(hasItem(name)) {
      inventory.erase(
         std::find_if(cbegin(inventory), cend(inventory),
            [&name](Item const& item){ return item.name == name; }));      
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Note I changed the function signature to use a const string reference, to prevent an unnecessary copy. In the lambda you can then also capture by reference.

In C++20 this will all be simplified and you can use [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2):

```
std::erase_if(inventory,
   [&name](Item const& item){ return item.name == name; });
```

p.s.
`hasValue` can be implemented using the [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) algorithm

```
bool Inventory::hasItem(string const& name) const {
   return std::any_of(cbegin(inventory), cend(inventory),
      [&name](Item const& item){ return item.name == name });
}
```

In C++20 this can even be written using ranges:

```
bool Inventory::hasItem(string const& name) const {
   return std::ranges::any_of(inventory, // input container
      [&name](string const& itemName){ return itemName == name }, // predicate
      &Item::name); // projection
}
```

Comment: You don't need to `std::move` the `name` into the lambda at all, you can capture it by reference instead: `[&](Item const& item){ return item.name == name }` Then you can change the declaration of `name` to `const string &name` to avoid a copy being made whenever `removeItem()` or `hasItem()` is called

Comment: If you're showing c++20 solutions, then you should show how `remove` can be used with a projection.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Changed it... I was thinking if there might be a specific reason to use copy by value, e.g. temporary objects or calling with a `char*`. I thought of using `std::string_view`, [but that also has a problem with temporary objects](https://foonathan.net/2017/03/string_view-temporary/).

Comment: @cigien I was looking into this, but cant really figure it out. The best I can come up with is `inventory.erase(std::ranges::find_if(inventory, [&](std::string const& itemName) { return itemName == name; }, &Item::name));`, but that doesn't seem better than the `std::erase_if` solution. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check [this](https://godbolt.org/z/rcsbs5) out :) Also, your `erase_if` solution is not equivalent. You'll erase *all* Items whereas you are only erasing the first one with `find`. `erase_if` is a substitute for the erase-remove idiom, not for erasing a single element.

Comment: @cigien wait what? I tried that, but it didn't compile. Now i have to find out what i did wrong

Comment: I'll go ahead and post an answer then. I think I can address the OP's question a little more directly.

Answer (score 0):

From c++20, if you want to remove all the elements of a range according to the value of a member, you can write this:

```
auto [begin, end] = std::ranges::remove(inventory, name, &Item::name);     
inventory.erase(begin, end);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PPP3hb).

If you just want to remove the first item, you can write:

```
inventory.erase(std::ranges::find(inventory, name, &Item::name));
```

In this case, you need to make sure that the item exists in the range, which you can do by comparing to the `end` of the range.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f4Mvsd).